Derivation of Noether Theorem in Wiki (on general Manifolds)
A naive question about derivation of Noether's theorem(Manifold/fiber bundle derivation). In the argumentation there appear equality
$$Q \left[ \int_N \mathcal{L} \, \mathrm{d}^n x \right] \approx \int_{\partial N} f^\mu [\varphi(x),\partial\varphi,\partial\partial\varphi,\ldots] \, ds_\mu $$
appearing also in next equality
$$ Q[\mathcal{L}(x)]\approx\partial_\mu f^\mu(x) $$
(where $\mathcal{L}(x):=\mathcal{L}[\varphi(x), \partial_\mu \varphi(x),x]$).
Questions:
(1) What means the wiggled equality "$\approx$"? A guess: Does it just used to indicate that we have there an equality on level of functionals (and not say just functions, numbers etc.)?
(2) Are the $f^\mu$ above on LHS independent of inserted sections $\varphi(x)$? (The last equation suggests this). More broadly, what actually are $f^\mu$ as mathematical objects? Functions or functionals in this derivation?
Moreover, why is their existence garaneed in first formula, ie why $Q \left[ \int_N \mathcal{L} \, \mathrm{d}^n x \right]$ must have such shape on right hand side as boundary with these $f^\mu$?


The wiggled equality $\approx$ usally means on-shell in this context. I.e., this kind of equality only holds for $\varphi$ that satisfy the Euler-Lagrange equations.

$f^\mu$ seems to be a function on jet space. Roughly speaking the coordinates of jet-spaces are given by
$$x^\mu, \phi, \partial \phi, \partial \partial \phi\,,$$
where the derivatives are treated as independent variables. For more details on the coordinates, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(mathematics).



Thank you for you answer. On the second point: So when you say that $f^{\mu}$ that it takes quadruples $(x^\mu, \phi, \partial \phi, \partial \partial \phi)$ it treats eg $\phi$ really as a coordinate itself and not as "$\phi$ firstly evaluated in $x$ and then insert in $f$, right? In other words, if $\phi$ are sections of a vector bundle $V \to M$ ($ M$ our mfld), $TM \to M$ the tangent bundle and $V(M)$  the space of sections, then $f_{\mu}$ as jet would have as domain $M \times V(M) \times (TM \otimes V)(M) \times (T^2 M \otimes V)(M)$, right?

It thinks so. Yes

I see, and concerning why actually the claimed on-shell identity $Q \left[ \int_N \mathcal{L} , \mathrm{d}^n x \right] \approx \int_{\partial N} f^\mu [\varphi(x),\partial\varphi,\partial\partial\varphi,\ldots] , ds_\mu $ holds for infinitesimal generator $Q$ - ie the image of a generator of corresp Lie algebra under usual local exp map - appears as actually be posed as an assumption (...wasn't reading carefully enough), and is nothing one can derive to hold for arbitrary such infinitelimal $Q$'s
